# tomcat8 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTimeoutPollingThread.run(OracleTimeoutPollingThread.java:150)

Tags: java, tomcat

I got below errors:

> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc
>   The web application [cms-api] registered the JDBC driver
>   [com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver] but failed to unregister it when
>   the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC
>   Driver has been forcibly unregistered. 09-May-2019 12:02:04.676 警告
>   [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [cms-api] appears to have started a thread named
>   [OracleTimeoutPollingThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) 
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTimeoutPollingThread.run(OracleTimeoutPollingThread.java:150)
>   09-May-2019 12:02:04.689 信息 [Thread-7]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8082"] 09-May-2019 12:02:04.692 信息 [Thread-7]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8011"] 09-May-2019 12:02:04.707 信息 [Thread-7]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8082"] 09-May-2019 12:02:04.708 信息 [Thread-7]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8011"]

Comment: welcome to SO. Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is nothing to worry about